# Generate correlated variables with fixed correlation but varying standard deviation

Tags: r, simulation, correlation

I would like to generate *k* variables from a multivariate normal distribution with a pre-specified mean, standard deviation and fixed correlation across the `k` variables.

I tried to do the following:

```
set.seed(10)
library(MASS)

k=10 #number of variables
mu <- rep(1,k) #mean of each variable
nobs <- 10000 #number of observations
sd <- rep(c(1,5),each=5) #standard deviation of each variable
cor <- 0.9 #correlation across variables

M <- matrix(cor,nrow=k,ncol=k) #variance covariance matrix
diag(M) <- sd^2 #desired standard deviations

data <- mvrnorm(nobs,mu,Sigma=M) #generate data
```

My problem is that I get the desired means and standard deviations but the correlation is far from the desired value.

```
 mean(cor(data))
[1] 0.3774926
```

I guess imposing specific standard deviations restricts the possible correlations I can obtain.

Is this indeed the case?

If so is there any way to get closer to the desired correlations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (generate the covariance matrix as per your requirement, by definition, `cov(x,y)=cor(x,y)*sigma_x*sigma_y)`:

```
M <- matrix(cor,nrow=k,ncol=k)*outer(sd,sd) # covariance matrix
diag(M) <- sd^2 #desired standard deviations

data <- mvrnorm(nobs,mu,Sigma=M) #generate data
mean(cor(data))
#[1] 0.9102620391642199
```

Comment: `cor_d <- cor(data); diag(cor_d) <- NA; mean(cor_d, na.rm = T)` gets rid of the diagonal entries = 1